# How to change the date formate in php?

Tags: php

I have a variable $date containing the date such as "12 2,2016" and i want to convert this date into following format.
February 12,2016.
how is this possible in php ?

Comment: How many seconds of research have you done on this?

Comment: <?php echo date('F jS, Y, g:i a',strtotime($created_at)); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it

```
    $date=date_create("12-2-2016");
    echo date_format($date,"F d, Y");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date=date_create("2016-02-12");  
echo date_format($date,"M d, y");
```

result: Feb 12, 2016